# In what way is this question "too broad"?

Tags: support

I asked [this question](https://biology.stackexchange.com/q/57923/23094) which, in essence, simply asks if lifestyle factors are controlled for in modern epidemiological studies. After first being flagged as "off-topic", then "more suitable for another site", the community seems to have finally settled on "too broad" as it's close reason.

As the question stands it could be answered in a single sentence by anyone actually involved in epidemiology. "Yes, we do try to control for various lifestyle factors, or "No, we don't tend to take them into account". I fail to see how this makes it too broad.

If no-one here is sufficiently qualified or experienced to answer such a question then it may have to sit for while, occasionally bumped to the home page on the off-chance, but I don't see how it helps coming up with a collection of spurious reasons why it should be closed.

If, on the other hand, I've missed some other interpretation of my question which is causing it to be defined as "too broad" I'd be grateful is someone could point it out and perhaps suggest how it might be edited to make the objective more clear.

Comment: I agree and voted to re-open. Get used to closed questions around here...